# Octave : How to change line color and width in drawRect

Tags: drawing, octave

:-) Hi, guys.

Is there any way to change the **line color** and **width** of function **drawRect** in Octave ?

According to its [reference](http://octave.sourceforge.net/geometry/function/drawRect.html), there's no property-value pair to set in this function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `drawRect` function does not accept a property-value pair, but it does return a graphics handle from where you can set any property:

```
r = drawRect (x, y, w, h);
set (r, "color", [1 0 0]); # set to red (RGB triplets)
set (r, "linewidth", 5);
```

Use `get (r)` to see a list of all properties, or read the manual section [graphics object properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Graphics-Object-Properties.html).

Comment: That's it! That's what I want! Thank you very much : )