# Octave: Change color in drawArrow

Tags: plot, octave

I found this answer

[[Octave : How to change line color and width in drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032785/octave-how-to-change-line-color-and-width-in-drawrect][1])

how to change the color in drawRect.

When I try the same for drawArrow, I get:

> > h=drawArrow(0,0,3,1,1,1,1,1);

```
h =

scalar structure containing the fields:

body = -12.469
head = -11.925
```

> > set(h,'color','r');

```
error: octave_base_value::array_value(): 
wrong type argument 'scalar struct'
error: set: H must be a graphics handle
```

What I am doing wrong here? For me it looks the same.

Thanks
Karl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should mention that you are using the octave-forge geometry package. drawArrow returns a struct with handles for the arrow body and head (as shown by your code) so you can and have to set them separately:

```
pkg load geometry
h = drawArrow (0,0,3,1,1,1,1,1);
set (h.body, "color", "r")
set (h.head, "facecolor", get(h.body, "color"))
```

[image: red arrow]

You can also set a border around the head with "edgecolor"

Comment: that sure is an odd choice of return object though ... I wonder why they didn't go for an hggroup which is purposely designed to hold graphics objects.

Comment: Btw, since you also point out that the use of the geometry package should be stated explicitly in snippets like these, I'd probably also add it to the snippet in the answer as well :p